# Netsuite Sales Order CSV import Error

Tags: csv, netsuite

I am getting this error all the time

"You must enter at least one line item for this transaction."

but i have filled the line item with a dummy non inventory item like below:

Sales Order Items : Item field with item name CP-MIGR-ITEM

Sales Order Items : Quantity field with item quantity 1

Sales Order Items : Amount field with Amount 10

Now i am not able to figure out, what's the problem. I have entered the line item why it is throwing the same error.

Comment: A couple of thoughts...  Have you made sure that on the Item field you have the settings set to "Names" instead of IDs?  Also, have you tried, just a test, to use the Internal ID instead of the Name?  And, of course, you do have headers in your file, correct?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have more than one line per sales order on a single cab file.

If you do then you need to split your cab into a header and detail file with the line items in the detail file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to add a column to your CSV file for Price Level
I use Sales Order Item: Price Level =Custom

Also are you doing Add or Update with this import.  If add do you have the same ExternalID value for each line item?
If update do you have the same transaction number value for each line item?

Also what type of item is CP-MIGR-ITEM?
(Service, other charge, non-inventory for Resale?). The system isn’t recognizing your item as a valid item to “sell” on a sales order. Make sure it is setup as a Non-Inventory item for resale

Answer (score 0):

Just got this error and I struggled for few hours and finally found the problem,

NS forces you to use multiple file to upload Sales Order Header and Line Item. You can't "hard code" it.

So as soon as I used my primary file with all the header info and the second file for the line item info, it works.

[See the image, it works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBhDK.png)